# assign value to new variable?

Tags: java, javascript, android

My code goes like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.Random;

/**
 *
 * @author Matt
 */
public class Deck {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random r = new Random();
    String[][] DeckOfCards = new String[13][4];
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    String suit[] = new String[4];
    String number[] = new String[13];
    ArrayList draw = new ArrayList();
                                            //setting up the deck
    suit[0]="Diamonds, ";
    suit[1]="Clubs, ";
    suit[2]="Hearts, ";
    suit[3]="Spades, ";

    number[0]="Ace of ";
    number[1]="Two of ";
    number[2]="Three of ";
    number[3]="Four of ";
    number[4]="Five of ";
    number[5]="Six of ";
    number[6]="Seven of ";
    number[7]="Eight of ";
    number[8]="Nine of ";
    number[9]="Ten of ";
    number[10]="Jack of ";
    number[11]="Queen of ";
    number[12]="King of ";

                                    //dealing the initial hand

    for(j=0;j<3;j++){

        for(i=0;i<12;i++){

            DeckOfCards[i][j]=""+number[i]+suit[j];
            draw.add(DeckOfCards[i][j]);
            //System.out.println(DeckOfCards[i][j]);
        }
        //System.out.println("");
       // System.out.println("");
    }

    ArrayList drawn = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList hand = new ArrayList();
    int u;


    for(u=1;u<6;u++){   
        k=r.nextInt(52);

        if(!drawn.contains(k)){    

            //System.out.println(draw.get(k));
            hand.add(u+" "+draw.get(k).toString());
            drawn.add(k);

            }
        else{
               u--;
            }

              }
            System.out.println(hand.toString());
```

but the last if statement:

```
            if(!drawn.contains(k)){
            hand.add(u+" "+draw.get(k).toString());
            drawn.add(k);)
```

always stops the compiling say that I need to assign the new variable a return value?  k is already assigned a value, before the if statement. It seems to work when I put the random k statement inside the if statement, but that makes it worthless, no? No errors in the editor itself but when I compile, it gives me this:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 41, Size: 36
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
    at deck.Deck.main(Deck.java:74)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

I'm completely out of ideas on how to solve this.

Comment: try to save `u+" "+draw.get(k).toString()` in a new variable before adding it

Answer (score 1):

There are not enough cards in your deck.
You are getting and index out bounds because you are trying to access `draw.get(41)` which doesnt exist because `draw` is only 36 in size. This is because your initialization of `draw` is incorrect. Your buggy code is:

```
for(j=0;j<3;j++){

        for(i=0;i<12;i++){

            DeckOfCards[i][j]=""+number[i]+suit[j];
            draw.add(DeckOfCards[i][j]);
            //System.out.println(DeckOfCards[i][j]);
        }
        //System.out.println("");
       // System.out.println("");
    }
```

in the above only adds 3 suits, 12 of each suit. (36 cards). You should be adding 4 suits, 13 of each suit. Perhaps you meant to say less than OR EQUAL TOO `for (j=0; j<=3; j++)`  instead of just LESS THAN.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to draw one of 52 random cards, but you only have 36 cards in your deck:

```
for(j=0;j<3;j++){  // should be j<4

    for(i=0;i<12;i++){  // should be i<13

        DeckOfCards[i][j]=""+number[i]+suit[j];
        draw.add(DeckOfCards[i][j]);
        //System.out.println(DeckOfCards[i][j]);
    }
    //System.out.println("");
   // System.out.println("");
}
```